# Writing list-directed data to unformatted I/O

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write unformatted data to a file. It should be simple, but at runtime it throws up the error;

> forrtl: severe (257): formatted I/O to unit open for unformatted transfers, unit 1, file ~/destination

It's difficult for me to give a working example since it is contained within a complex subroutine of a climate model, but my best attempt at representing it is;

```
      subroutine writev(par)
      real par(x,y)
      real var(x,y)

      var = sqrt(par)
      open (unit=1,file="~/destination",form="unformatted")
      write (1,*)var
      close(1)
      end
```

From what I can interpret, the error message is telling me that the data is formatted, but I can't see why this would be as I haven't asked it to format it anywhere apart from specifying that it is real type. Is there something glaringly obvious that I could be missing here?

The full strack trace is;

> forrtl: severe (257): formatted I/O to unit open for unformatted transfers, unit                                   1, file
>   ~/destination Image
>   PC                Routine            Line        Source
>   genie.exe          00000000008362B6  Unknown               Unknown 
>   Unknown genie.exe          00000000008354B6  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          00000000007E2612  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          0000000000796881  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          000000000079616E  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          00000000007D373E  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          0000000000467FF4  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          000000000046F06F  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          000000000043C793  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          0000000000461D73  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          0000000000403816  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown libc.so.6          000000376901D9F4  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown genie.exe          0000000000403729  Unknown
>   Unknown  Unknown
>
> real    0m1.673s user    0m0.031s sys     0m0.023s ERROR: !!!!!!!!!!
>   ERROR PROCESSING !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please post full stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unformatted I/O requires no/conflicts with the format specifier `*`. Using

```
write (1) var
```

should do the trick. See [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-9.html) for details.

BTW: Never use unit numbers below 10, they might have a special meaning (e.g. usually `6` is `STDOUT`). If your compiler supports it, use `open` with `newunit`.